# in a react-redux app,what will make an action dispatched update states in a reducer that does not have such an action in its condition

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux, dispatch

I dispatched an action in a react-redux application, the states of the reducer with that action was updated with the payload from the action as required. In addition to this, the states of the another reducer that does not not have such an action was updated with that same payload even when the corresponding action was not dispatched. what exactly is happening?

```
//my action for reducer 1
import { CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, FETCH_ALL, ITEMS_LOADING } from '../constants/actionTypes';
import * as api from '../api/index';

export const getPosts = () => async (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(setItemsLoading());
    const data = await api.fetchPosts
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch({ type: FETCH_ALL, payload: res.data });
        }).catch(() => {
            console.log("there is error");
        })

}
//my action for reducer 2
import { GET_POST } from '../constants/actionTypes';
import * as api from '../api/index';

export const getSinglePosts = (id) => (dispatch) => {
    return{
        type: GET_POST, payload: id
    }
}

//reducer 1
import { CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, FETCH_ALL, ITEMS_LOADING } from '../constants/actionTypes';
const initialState = {
    posts: [],
    allLoaded:false,
    loading: false
}
export default (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case DELETE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: state.posts.filter((post) => post._id !== action.payload)
            };
        case UPDATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: state.posts.map((post) => post._id === action.payload._id ? action.payload : post)
            };
        case FETCH_ALL:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: action.payload,
                allLoaded:true,
                loading: false
            };
        case CREATE:
            return {
                ...state,
                posts: [action.payload, ...state.posts]
            };
        case ITEMS_LOADING:
            return {
                ...state,
                loading: true
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//reducer2

import {
    GET_POST
} from '../constants/actionTypes';

const initialState = {
    info:null,
    postLoaded:false
}

export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    switch (action.type) {
        case GET_POST:
            return {
                ...state,
                postLoaded: true,
                info:action.payload
            };
        default:
            return state;
    }
}

//homepage where action was dispatched
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import PageNavbar from './PageNavbar';
import { getPosts } from '../../myActions/posts';
import { useSelector, useDispatch } from 'react-redux';
//import { getSinglePosts } from '../../myActions/single';
import { useHistory } from 'react-router-dom';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';

function MyBlog() {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  useEffect(() => {
    dispatch(getPosts());
  }, [dispatch]);
  const posts = useSelector((state) => state.posts.posts);
  const history = useHistory();
  return (
    <>
      <PageNavbar />
      <div align="center">
        {posts.map((post) => (
          <>
            <Button href="/user/singlePost" color="primary">
              {post.title}
            </Button>
            <br />
          </>))}
      </div>
    </>
  )
}

export default MyBlog
//root reducer
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
import posts from './myposts';
import error from './error';
import auth from './auth';
import info from './singlePost';

export default combineReducers({
    info,
    posts,
    auth,
    error
})
//thanks
```

Comment: From what I see `GET_POST` action is not dispatched. So reducer 2 should not change. Can you share how you have created your root reducer. Also what exactly is changing in reducer 2 ?

Comment: Easwer I have added the root reducer to the code above. The empty posts array changes to an array of post as expected. Also the 'info:null' changes to 'info:[...]' that is the info changes to an array of post even when the GET_POST action was not dispatched. thanks

Comment: Looks fine from this piece of code. Try debug from the redux dev tools to see which all actions are getting triggered. If `GET_POST` is getting dispatched, you'll see a log.

Comment: Easwer I added the line that caused the error above. It was a typo error. Thanks a lot  for your concern.

Comment: @Easwar It was a typo error.I typed `export const GET_POST="FETCH_ALL"` instead of `export const GET_POST="GET_POST"` Thanks a lot  for your concern.